# Javascript Object Prototype 'this' empty in Promise

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure why in this code snippet the last 'this' in the open method is returning an empty object. Outside of the arrow function 'this' returns the correct information. Using an arrow function should essentially bind it to the same 'this' I thought, but it's just returning undefined...

'wrap' is a wrapper function for my async code.

```
let Client = wrap(async function (host, opts) {
    if (!(this instanceof Client)) {
        return new Client(host, opts);
    }

    this.host = host;
    this.opts = opts;

    await this.open();

    return this;
});

Client.prototype.open = wrap(async function () {
    // Omitted most code here as it doesn't influence the problem at all.

    console.log(this); // Works

    (function (test) {
        console.log(test); // Works
    })(this);

    await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log(this); // Obviously Undefined
    });

    await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log(this); // Works, but is ugly.
    }.bind(this));

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log(this); // Returns empty object {}. Why?
    });
});
```

If I put the logic in the main Client code, or don't use prototype everything works fine. But the second I prototype it, it breaks.

Comment: var _t = this;//now i am free to reference the var from inside of the promise, because it was declared in the calling scope.

Comment: That's what I'm currently using to go around it, but I'd rather not have to do it if I don't have to. I'm really confused at why the arrow function is behaving the way it is. Outside of prototypes it works perfectly fine, so is it some intrinsic property of Object.prototype that's causing the issue?

Comment: arrow functions get a lexical _this_ at parse time, not a reflected or applied _this_ like normal functions. in short, you can't use arrow function to define methods or inherit _this_ from the caller.

Comment: Please mark as answered